# installing GnuGPG with Thunderbird on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, email, encryption, gpg, thunderbird

How can I install GnuPG on my CentOS 7 system?

I want to use GnuPG alongside Thunderbird and Enigmail to manage pgp keys, as per [the instructions in this link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/digitally-signing-and-encrypting-messages).

The problem is that the download instructions I find for linux all have to do with Debian.  [Here is an example](https://www.gnupg.org/download/).

**EDIT**

typing `which gpg` resulted in `/usr/bin/gpg`, however, it is not clear that this is the same aspect of GnuGPG that needs to be integrated with Thunderbird and Enigmail to manage gpg keys.  Before this question can be considered answered, I need to know that GnuPG is installed in a way that can run with Thunderbird and Enigmail.  Thus, the answer would give instructions for checking status, and instructions for downloading if it is not properly installed yet.  I imagine this might only take several lines of actual methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. install Enigmail

```
Thunderbird > Add-ons Menu > Enigmail
```

2. If you do not already have a PGP key, generate one:

```
gpg --gen-key
```

(follow its prompts to complete the process; default values are generally fine)
 3. Restart Thunderbird. Enigmail will probably auto-detect the presence of your GnuPG keychain and use it. If it does not, point it to your GnuPG dir:

```
Thunderbird > Enigmail > Key Management
```

4. In the Key Management window, select

```
File > Import Keys from File
```

and show Enigmail to your /home/$USER/.gnupg directory. Import your key; ignore errors from Enigmail that it already knew about your key. You should now see your key listed in the Key Management window.
 5. Email somebody!

Comment: <p>It looks like Enigmail menus have changed a bit. Go to Enigmail > Key Management.</p> <p>In Key Management window, go to File > Import Keys from File.</p><p>You gnupg folder is in /home/$USER/.gnupg, so point to that directory and Enigmail figures out the rest. I just tested it and it told me that the key already had been added to Enigmail; ignore that message. As long as you see your key listed in Key Management, you should now be ready to go.

Comment: You should not run gpg --gen-key as root. You are generating a key for yourself as a user, not as root.

Comment: I have a related question, are you willing to help me with it also?  Here is the link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182974/creating-and-sending-a-self-signed-public-key-using-gnupg-in-centos-7/182976#182976

Answer (score 0):

You can just install `gnupg2 (2.0.22) from the`base` repo, but chances are that it is already installed (as it was on my CentOS system).