# creating and sending a self-signed public key using GnuPG in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, email, encryption, gpg, key-authentication

I know that I can create a GPG keypair from the CentOS 7 terminal by typing `gpg --gen-key` and following the resulting steps, but **how can I make sure that the resulting public key is self-signed?  And how can I send the resulting key via email to a remote computer?**

I know that I can send an email with an attachment using mailx from the command line as follows:

```
echo "this is the body of the email" | mailx -s"Subject" -a public.key Someone@Domain.com
```

But the mailx code snipped assumes that the key is available in a file.  In reality, the key is locked up in a keyring and needs other syntax in order for it to be accessed.

**EDIT**

I am following @HaukeLaging's advice.  I have created a new key, but when I type `gpg --list-sigs` in the command line, I get the following results:

```
/home/username/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
-----------------------------------------
pub   4096R/CODE1 2015-02-04
uid                  User Name <username@domainname.com>
sig 3        CODE1 2015-02-04  User Name <username@domainname.com>
sub   4096R/CODE2 2015-02-04
sig          CODE1 2015-02-04  User Name <username@domainname.com>
```

Which of these key codes is the public key?  And Which is the private key?  I do not want to accidentally send the private key to anyone.

**EDIT#2**

As per @HaukeLaging's response to EDIT#1, I tried:

```
`sudo gpg --armor --export CODE1 >/home/username/my_public_cert.asc`
```

but the result is an empty file when I then `cd /home/username/` and `ls -al`.

Also,

```
gpg --list-packets /home/username/my_public_cert.asc
```

resulted in `gpg: processing message failed: Unknown system error`

**Why is `gpg --armor --export CODE1 >/home/username/my_public_cert.asc` producing an empty file?**

Comment: The `pub` line refers to the mainkey, the `sub` line to the subkey. Both are key pairs consisting of an public key and a private key. You need `--export-secret-keys` or `--export-secret-subkeys` to export a private key. You can check the exported file with `gpg --list-packets file.asc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the public key you want to export:

```
gpg --list-public-keys
```

Look at the line marked 'pub'; it displays your public key type and number. For instance:

```
pub  1024D/5000280F 2009-07-10
```

Use the number to do your export:

```
gpg --armor --export 5000280F > klaatu_pubkey.asc
```

Check to make sure it worked:

```
cat klaatu_pubkey.asc
```

As long as it's not empty, you can send that file to your friends.

Since the PGP model is based on a web of trust, it is beneficial to get your public key out there into the world so people can start using it. The easiest way to do that is to post it to a key server:

```
gpg --export send-keys 5000280F --keyserver keys.fedoraproject.org
```

Key-servers mirror one another periodically, so your key will propagate and people who receive signed emails from you can just download/import your pub key from the network of key servers.

Comment: I followed your steps, but i have two follow up questions related to how to get the keys to be used properly.  Are you willing to help me with them also?  The link to the server-side aspect of the problem is here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183212/how-can-i-ensure-that-received-email-is-encrypted

Comment: The link to the end-user/Thunderbird aspect of the problem is here: http://superuser.com/questions/874303/how-can-i-force-thunderbird-to-encrypt-an-email-and-its-attachments

Answer (score 4):

**self-signatures**

OpenPGP certificates consist of several components.

Always:

- exactly one mainkey
- at least one user ID (UID)

Usually:

- at least one subkey

All components except for the mainkey become part of the certificate by being signed by the mainkey. You cannot create a certificate (with GnuPG) which contains components without self-signature. You have to delete the self-signature afterwards to reach such a situation.

You can see the signatures by running

```
gpg --list-sigs
```

or

```
gpg --with-colons --list-sigs
```

**attaching a certificate to an email**

If you want to attach the certificate you have to export it to a file first:

```
gpg --armor --export $key_id >my_cert.asc
```

or

```
gpg --armor --output my_cert.asc --export $key_id
```

Comment: Please see EDIT I just added to the end of my OP.  Which key_id do I use to output the public key?  Thank you and +1 for your time so far.

Comment: @CodeMed `CODE1` is the key ID.

Comment: I tried `sudo gpg --armor --export CODE1 >/home/username/my_public_cert.asc`, but the result is an empty file when I then `cd /home/username/` and `ls -al`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @CodeMed Why `sudo`? That isn't some magic software you need for everything...

Comment: Because `nano` alone opened an empty file, so I was double checking with `sudo`.  In other situations, `sudo nano` shows contents in a file when `nano` alone opens an empty file.

Comment: Please see EDIT#2 at the end of my OP for the results of `gpg --list-packets file.asc`

Comment: Why is `gpg --armor --export CODE1 >/home/username/my_public_cert.asc` producing an empty file?

Comment: You posted `4096R/CODE1` as output though that is not the real output, of course. I thought it was more than obvious that "CODE1 is the key ID" means: "What you deleted and replaced by `CODE1` is the key ID...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know self-signed have sense in PKI. PGP/GPG use different idea - web of trust. So you should have signed your public key from your correspondent and sign his/her key too

Comment: Your answer turned up in my "low quality review" queue :). Perhaps you could expand it a little to contain more explanation and some references.